# Differential of the inversion of Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\iota \colon G\to G$ denote the inversion. If $e$ is the identity of $G$, prove that: $$\text d \iota _e = -\text {id} _{T_e G}.$$
I understand that the differential at $e$ should be an involution, since $$\iota \circ \iota = \text{id}_G$$
implies that $$\text d \iota _e \circ \text d \iota _e=\text d (\iota \circ \iota)_e=\text d(\text {id} _G)_e=\text {id} _{T_e G}.$$
However I don't know how to conclude the thesis from this. Any hint?

Comment: An involved solution seems to appear here: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=605960

Comment: And I think that you can find some hints here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209682/pushforward-of-inverse-map-around-the-identity

Comment: Thank you @Siminore, indeed the second link was helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your approach, you can only say the eigenvalue is either $1$ or $-1$, therefore impossible to answer your question.

If you use the curve definition of tangent vector, the result can't be more obvious: 
$$
\iota: g(t)\mapsto g^{-1}(t), g(0)=e.
$$
Then by chain rule:
$$
d\iota_e(\dot g(0))=\dot g^{-1}(0).
$$
However, $g(t)g^{-1}(t)=e$ and therefore by Leibniz rule:
$$
\dot g(0)=-\dot g^{-1}(0).
$$
and consequently,
$$
d\iota_e(\dot g(0))=-\dot g(0), \forall \dot g(0)\in T_eG.
$$

Note that a Lie group $G$ is necessarily a symmetric space with the inversion symmetry $S_g$ at $g\in G$ given by $S_g: h\mapsto gh^{-1}g$. So that, every inversion symmetry is involutive and in particular, at $g=e$, $S_g$ coincides with the group inversion. This roughly says you should expect to have a involutive map in the first place.

---

**Honest check of Leibniz rule:**

If $G$ is a matrix Lie group, group multiplication is the matrix multiplication and we are done. For a general Lie group, the situation is similar: $\forall a,b\in G$ parameterized by local coordinates $a=a(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ and $b=b(y^1,\dots,y^n)$, their product is smooth and a map from $(x^1,\dots,x^n;y^1,\dots,y^n)$ to $a\cdot b\in G$ is well defined:
$$
a\cdot b(x^1,\dots,x^n;y^1,\dots,y^n)=a(x^1,\dots,x^n)\cdot b(y^1,\dots,y^n)
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}a\cdot b(x^1(t),\dots,x^n(t);y^1(t),\dots,y^n(t))&=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial a\cdot b}{\partial x^i}\frac{dx^i}{dt}+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial a\cdot b}{\partial y^i}\frac{dy^i}{dt}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}(R_b(a(t)))+\frac{d}{dt}(L_a(b(t)))\\
&=R_{b*}\dot a(t)+L_{a*}\dot b(t)
\end{split}
$$
In our case, we take $a=g, b=g^{-1}$ and the rest follows.

Comment: Hi Troy, thank you. Your proof seems to rely on the fact that: $$\frac {\text d}{\text {dt}}|_0(\sigma _1 \sigma _2)=\sigma _1 (0)\dot \sigma _2 (0)+\dot \sigma _1 (0) \sigma _2(0),$$ is that right? How do you prove that?

Comment: @pppqqq $g(0)=g^{-1}(0)=e$.

Comment: @pppqqq: Yes I think so too: This requires at least some honest check!

Comment: @TroyWoo: Can you elaborate on how this gives the product rule, please?

Comment: @Freeze_S It should not be different from a matrix Lie group case. I added a paragraph in the answer.

Comment: @TroyWoo your answer only makes sense in $\mathbb{R}$. You cannot assume Leibniz rule for an abstract Lie group $G$.

Comment: @ReneCabrera you make sure you finished reading my post before you down vote?

Comment: @ReneCabrera It surprises me that you are actually a math grad student...have you ever read e.g. Kobayashi and Nomizu's Foundations of Differential Geometry, or Loos's Symmetric space? Can you not find Leibniz product rule in those books?

Answer (score 5):

*It can be sooo simple...* :)

Applying the multiplication infinitesimally:
$$[\alpha]+\mathrm{d}\iota[\alpha]=[\alpha]+[\iota\circ\alpha]=\mathrm{d}\mu[(\alpha,\alpha^{-1})]=[\mu(\alpha,\alpha^{-1})]=[e]=0$$
*(Note that all equality signs in this line are for real.)*

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that $\iota$ is an involution, you cannot conclude that $d\iota_{e} = -\text{id}_{T_{e}G}$. For example, think of the involution $R$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which consists in rotation by $\pi$ around the $z$-axis. This has differential at the origin given by
\begin{equation}
 \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   -1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & -1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array} } \right].
\end{equation}

A nice way to see that $d\iota_{e} = -\text{id}_{T_{e}G}$ is to make use of 1-parameter subgroups. 
 Given an element $X \in T_{e}G$, we have the 1-parameter subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$: 
\begin{equation} \Phi_{X}(t) = \text{exp}(tX). \end{equation}
 (Note that we are identifying the tangent space $T_{e}G$ with $\text{Lie}(G)$, the Lie algebra of $G$, and that exp is the exponential map: exp$: \text{Lie}(G) \to G$.)

Since $\Phi_{X}'(0) = X$, and that \begin{equation}\iota \circ \Phi_{X}(t) = \text{exp}(tX)^{-1} = \text{exp}(-tX) = \Phi_{-X}(t), \end{equation} we have that 
\begin{equation} d\iota_{e}(X) = d\iota_{e} \circ d(\Phi_{X})_{0}(\frac{d}{dt}) = d(\iota \circ \Phi_{X})_{0}(\frac{d}{dt}) = \Phi_{-X}'(0) = -X.\end{equation}

Note that making use of the 1-parameter subgroup often comes in handy in problems like this involving differentials of maps on Lie groups.