# $\exp$ of a Lie group is a local diffeomorphism at all points of the Lie algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am trying to show that for any Lie group $G$ with $T_e G=:\mathfrak{g}$, $\exp:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G$ satisfies that $d_X \exp : T_X \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow T_{\exp(X)}G$ is invertible for any $X \in \mathfrak{g}$.

I know that $d_e \exp:\mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ is the identity map.

My attempt was to use this fact by rescaling so that we arrive in a neighborhood of the identity where $d\exp$ is invertible, and then use the fact that $\exp$ is a group homomorphism on $1$-parameter subgroups.

In detail:

We can assume there's a ball $B(0, \varepsilon) \subset \mathfrak{g}$ on which $d \exp$ is invertible, once we put a Euclidian metric on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $X \in \mathfrak{g} = M$ and take now $r := \frac{\varepsilon}{2 \lVert X \rVert}$. Then $\lVert rX \rVert = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, so $rX \in B(0, \varepsilon)$. We have:

$$ X = \left[ \frac{1}{r} \right] (r X) + \left\{\frac{1}{r}\right\} (rX) = k (rX) + f (rX) $$

with $k\in \mathbb N$ and $0 \leq f < 1$.

Since $\exp(tY)$ is the integral curve of the left invariant field generated by $Y$ and this integral curve is a $1$-parameter subgroup, we have
$$ \exp(Y) = \exp(k(rY) + f(rY)) = \exp(rY)^k \exp(f rY)  $$

Now take $V \in T_X \frak{g}$. An integral curve passing through $X$ with speed $V$ at time $t=0$ is $Y(t) = X + tV$.

We have:
\begin{align*}
    d_X \exp(V) &= \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} \exp(Y(t)) \\
    &=\left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} \exp(rY(t))^k \exp(f rY(t))
\end{align*}

I don't know how to take it from here. I'm thinking I should use the fact that the rescaling maps $Y \mapsto rY$ and $Y \mapsto fY$ have invertible differentials, but I don't know what to do with the fact that we have a composition of multiplications in the RHS.

EDIT: I made some progress.

Setting $\phi_\lambda:\frak{g} \rightarrow \frak{g}$, $\phi_\lambda(Y) = \lambda Y$ we  have:
$$ \exp(Y) = (\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y)  (\exp \circ \phi_{fr})(Y) $$
and
\begin{align*}
    d_X \exp(V) &= \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} \exp(Y(t)) \\
    &=\left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} (\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y(t)) (\exp \circ \phi_{fr})(Y(t))
\end{align*}

Let $R$ denote right multiplication in $G$ and $L$ left multiplication. By the Leibniz rule (see [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904231/differential-of-the-inversion-of-lie-group}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904231/differential-of-the-inversion-of-lie-group%7D)) we have:
\begin{align*}
    \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} & (\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y(t)) (\exp \circ \phi_{fr})(Y(t))\\
    &= d_{(\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y(0))} R_{\exp \circ \phi_{fr}(Y(0))} \left(
        \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} (\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y(t))
    \right) \\
    &+ d_{(\exp \circ \phi_{fr})(Y(0))} L_{(\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y(0))} \left(
        \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} (\exp \circ \phi_{fr})(Y(t))
        \right) \\
    &= d_{(\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(X)} R_{\exp \circ \phi_{fr}(X)} \left(
        \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right\rvert_{t=0} (\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(Y(t))
    \right) \\
    &+ \left( d_{(\exp \circ \phi_{fr})(X)} L_{(\exp \circ \phi_r)^k(X)} \right) \circ \left( d_{\phi_{fr}(X)} \exp \right) \circ \left(  d_X \phi_{fr} \right) (V)
\end{align*}

The key point is that $d_{\phi_{fr}(X)} \exp = d_{fr X} \exp$ is invertible because $frX \in B(0, \varepsilon)$, so the whole composition of differentials in the second term is invertible, and by induction on $k$ so will be the other term. So I am left with a sum of invertible matrices. However, this is not always invertible. Is it invertible in this case?

Comment: Since you know that the differential of $\mathrm{exp}$ is the identity, wouldn't it be much easier to simply use the inverse function theorem?

Comment: @G.Blaickner The inverse function theorem only tells me that $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism around $0 \in \frak{g}$. I want to see that it is a diffeomorphism around every point $X \in \frak{g}$. I think I don't realise what usage of the inverse function theorem you have in mind.

Comment: You are trying to prove a false statement. Work out the example of $SU(2)$.

Comment: Thank you, @MoisheKohan . What I was trying to prove actually is that the set $\{ X \in \mathfrak{g}: \exp(X) = e \}$ is discrete and I thought this stronger statement was needed. Is there anything known in general about the set of $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ where $d_X \exp$ is not bijective - for example, is this set itself discrete? And is there some simpler way to prove that $\{ X \in \mathfrak{g}: \exp(X) = e \}$ is discrete?

Comment: It is not discrete. As I said, look at SU(2).