# Push-forward of inverse map

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, pushforward, tangent-spaces

If I define the inverse map in a Lie group $G$ as,

$$i: G \rightarrow G,\quad i(g) = g^{-1}, \forall g \in G  \tag1$$

I think that the associated push-forward would be,

$$i_*: T_gG \rightarrow T_{g^{-1}}G, \quad i_*(X|_g) = X|_{g^{-1}} \equiv -X|_g, \forall X \in \mathfrak{X}(G)  \tag2$$

Where, $\mathfrak{X}(G)$ is the set of tangent vector fields in $G$

Is Eq. (2) the action of $i_*$ or it is wrong? The part which I'm not very sure is $i_*(X|_g) = X|_{g^{-1}}$. I have this doubt because in other posts (e.g. [Pushforward of Inverse Map around the identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209682/pushforward-of-inverse-map-around-the-identity) or [Differential of the inversion of Lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904231/differential-of-the-inversion-of-lie-group?noredirect=1&lq=1)) it is handle $T_eG$ and not $T_gG$ in general.

Comment: What does $-g$ mean in an arbitrary Lie group? Did you mean $g^{-1}$?

Comment: yes, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the proposed equation makes no sense, as quantities on the two sides live in different tangent spaces: For $X \in T_g G$, we have $-X_g \in T_g G$ but $X_{g^{-1}} \in T_{g^{-1}} G$, and these spaces coincide only if $g^2 = e$.

On the other hand, unwinding definitions gives $$i = R_{g^{-1}} \circ i \circ L_{g^{-1}}$$ (here, $L_h$ and $R_h$ respectively denote left and right multiplication by $h$), so differentiating gives
$$T_g i = T_e R_{g^{-1}} \circ T_e i \circ T_g L_{g^{-1}},$$ and using that $T_e i \cdot Y = - Y$ gives what you wanted in your equation (2):
$$\boxed{T_g i \cdot X = T_e R_{g^{-1}} (-T_g L_{g^{-1}} \cdot X) = -T_g (L_{g^{-1}} \circ R_{g^{-1}}) \cdot X }.$$
For a general Lie group this is already fully simplified, but for a linear Lie group $G \leq GL(n, \Bbb R)$ the usual matrix identifications give
$$\boxed{T_A i \cdot X = -A^{-1} X A^{-1}} .$$

*Remark* The proposed equation is wrong for a different reason, too, namely that the value of the vector field $X$ at one point on $G$ need not be related it its value at any other point. Such a relation is forced, however, if we restrict our attention to left- or right-invariant vector fields.

Comment: I don't see how you get by differentiating the equationwith the tangent spaces. Could you develop it? (Actually I've made a new post for that because I found that equation but I dindn't undertand it. The post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2999933/how-does-push-forward-of-inverse-map-look-like). I've made some calculus but I don't obtain that formula

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Using the star notation for pushforward, differentiating the identity $i = R_{g^{-1}} \circ i \circ L_{g^{-1}}$ gives $i_* = (R_{g^{-1}})_* \circ i_* \circ (L_{g^{-1}})_*$. The idea here is to rewrite $i$ so that where $i_*$ appears on the r.h.s., it's the pushforward at $1_G$, for which we already know the identity you wrote down.

Comment: I don't see how to do the differentiation. Deriving respect to some parameter? I don't see it. In that post I wrote what I get

Comment: The relevant fact is the chain rule for pushforwards: The pushforward of a composition is the composition of the pushforwards, i.e., $(F \circ G)_* = F_* \circ G_*$.

Comment: And how do you what part is in $T_e$ and in $T_g$, because in your formula for $i_*$ appears both?

Comment: That's written in my answer. On the right-hand side, $T_g L_{g^{-1}}$ maps $T_g G$ to $T_{L_{g^{-1}}(g)} G = T_e G$, then $T_e i$ maps $T_e G$ to $T_e G$, and finally $T_g R_{g^{-1}}$ maps $T_e G$ to $T_{R_{g^{-1}}(e)} G = T_{g^{-1}} G$.

Comment: Ok, great, got it. Really thanks for your time and your answer

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. For a clear exposition of some basics about pushforwards, I recommend $\S~$3 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Answer (score 1):

No, that doesn't make since. You are defining a map from $T_gG$ into $T_{g^{-1}}G$. It maps $X(\in T_gG)$ into what? Since $X\in T_gG$, $X\notin T_{g^{-1}}G$, and therefore it makes no sense to assert that $i^*(X)=-X$. Of course, there is one exception to the assertion “Since $X\in T_gG$, $X\notin T_{g^{-1}}G$”, which is precisely when $g=e$. But that's the only exception.

Comment: Then, how should Eq. (2) be written?

Comment: I don't think that there is a simple answer to that question.

Comment: Is $i_*(X|_g) = X|_{g^{-1}}$ right or is this wrong too?

Comment: It is worst than wrong: it makes no sense (by the reason that I explained in my answer).

Comment: I didn't say $X \in T_gG$. $X|_g \in T_gG$ or at least this is the way I learnt it in class, so $X|_{g^{-1}}$ should belong to  $T_{g^{-1}}G$

Comment: If $X$ is not an element of $T_gG$, what is it then? A vector field defined in $G$? Or a left-invariant vector field, perhaps?

Comment: A vector field in $G$ as it's explained in the question

Comment: Then, there is no reason why $i^*(X|_g)$ should be $\pm X|_{g^{-1}}$.

Comment: Why? I'm just getting more confused

Comment: Take a concrete example. Suppose, say that $G$ is $(\mathbb{R},+)$. Suppose that  the vector field $X$ is, say, $X(f)(a)=(a+3)f'(a)$. Finally, take $g=1$ and compute $i^*(X|_1)$ and $X|_{-1}$ (in this case, $i(x)=-x$, of course). They are different.

Comment: If $i_*: T_gG \rightarrow T_{g^{-1}}G$, then $i_*(X|_g) \in T_{g^{-1}}G$. Now recall that $X|_{g^{-1}} \in T_{g^{-1}}G$, so maybe it is right that $i_*(X|_g) = X|_{g^{-1}}$