# How does push-forward of inverse map look like?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In the post [Differential of the multiplication and inverse maps on a Lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1740179/differential-of-the-multiplication-and-inverse-maps-on-a-lie-group), second answer, appears the following solution for the push-forward of the inverse map:

$\iota_{*,a}(Y_a) = -(r_{a^{-1}})_* (\ell_{a^{-1}})_* Y_a \tag1$

In the second answer it is explained that applying the chain rule to

$\iota(x) = r_{a^{-1}} \circ \iota \circ l_{a^{-1}}(x) \tag2$

you obtain Eq. (1). I guess that the chain rule has to be applied by derivation respect to some parameter $t$. Doing that I get:

$$\frac{d\iota(x)}{dt} = \frac{dr_{a^{-1}}(\iota(l_a^{-1}(x)))}{d(\iota(l_a^{-1}(x)))}\cdot \frac{d(\iota(l_a^{-1}(x)))}{d(l_{a^{-1}}(x))}\cdot \frac{dl_{a^{-1}}(x)}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dt} = r_{a^{-1}}\frac{d(\iota(l_a^{-1}(x)))}{d(l_{a^{-1}}(x))}l_{a^{-1}}\frac{dx}{dt} \tag3$$

And I don't know how to continue, so, I don't see how Eq. (1) can be obtained by this method.

Comment: The chain rule for pushforwards is just that $(F \circ G)_{\ast} = F_{\ast} \circ G_{\ast}$.

Comment: How do you prove it? Sorry, I'm a roockie in this branch of maths

Comment: In coordinates this is just the multivariable chain rule.